# Json to XLIFF coversion and XLIFF to Json conversion tools

Tags: xliff

Can someone explain the details on how to translate json files to XLIFF and XLIFF files to json? Are there any tools to do this easily? We are using JMVC frame work and i18n internationalization library in our company to build a web site. We are using json files in our framework, but the translation company needs XLIFF files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Okapi tools' JSON filter to extract/merge JSON data into/from XLIFF
See http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/index.php?title=JSON_Filter
and http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/

-ys

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you also please point me to specific examples on how to do this using Okapi tools?